# Difference between score and predict

Tags: machine-learning

What is the difference between .score and .predict? As I recall we input two parameters in score which are(features, target) while in predict we give only (X_train). What is the main difference and what to use when?

Answer (score 2):

score is used for evaluating the quality of a model’s predictions

predict is used to predict the output for a given input